Renaming a Database in an Availability group without resynchronizing the secondary nodes again
Let's say we have a three-node Availability Group (AG) with nodes Node1, Node2, and Node3. We have a requirement to rename a database within the AG, but unfortunately, the database is 20TB in size. Normally, the recommended approach is to remove the database from the AG, rename it, and then add it back, which requires a full backup and restore. This process would take a substantial amount of time, and I am trying to avoid the resynchronization and minimize downtime.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Here is what I am considering doing. I have tested this, and it seems to work, but I wanted to see if there is anything I might be missing.
Steps

Stop backups on the database
Remove the database from AG.
Rename the database on node 1 and perform log backup with norecovery option.
Restore the above log backup on node 2 with recovery and node 3 with norecovery.
Rename the DB on node2 and perform a log backup with norecovery on node2.
Restore the node2 log backup on node 1 with norecovery and node 3 with recovery.
Rename the DB on node 3 and take log backup with norecovery on node 3.
Restore the node3 log backup on node 1 with recovery and node2 with norecovery.
Add the DB back to AG.

